# iPhone application localization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my MainViewController I am using this code:

```
static NSBundle *bundle = nil;

+(void)setLanguage:(NSString *)l {

NSLog(@"preferredLang: %@", l);
NSString *path = [[ NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource:l ofType:@"lproj" ];
bundle = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] retain];}


+(void)initialize {

NSUserDefaults* defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray* languages = [defs objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *current = [[languages objectAtIndex:0] retain];
[self setLanguage:current];
}

+(NSString *)get:(NSString *)key alter:(NSString *)alternate {
return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:alternate table:nil];}
```

And in application main:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tr", @"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Its working fine and showing the turkish language in my application other than the iPhone native language. But, I want to allow the user to change the language through buttons, like if user clicks on english language button, a dialogue should open that application will be restarted and your lang will be changed.

How to do that?

I am using iOS 5....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app should not provide a custom language selector.
Users probably have prior knowledge on how to change the preferred language by navigating to  General > International > Language in the Settings application.

Further details in Apple's [Internationalization Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i)